# Im using a pluing called JavascriptSpellCheck and I need to set some dymamic text into the textarea, its posible?

Tags: javascript, jquery, spell-checking

I have a simple form, with a textarea field, I need to append some texts to textarea with `JavaScriptSpellCheck` plugin attached.

I have tried:
`.append`, `.html`, `.text` using jQuery , and javascript but nothing happens.

I read the documentation (http://www.javascriptspellcheck.com/Object_Reference) but I can't get something useful, there any way possible?

Thanks in advance!!!

My are simple, just a common simple textarea, but when the plugin is attached I cant add a dynamic text to the textarea, the situation :
When the user click on "Tips or Examples", I need to append/add to my textarea.. but i cant destroy the plugin or make something to add the text,

$('textarea').spellAsYouType({
      checkGrammar:true,
     showLanguagesInContextMenu: false,
     userInterfaceTranslation:'es',
     theme:'bright'
});

I try to add some text but doesnt work!, I see only the words 'test' but only work if the user type the word on the textarea, I need to make this 'dynamic'... when the plugin is attached my textarea is hidden and add some divs on my form.

Capture (Firebug/HTML)
http://psylux.com.ar/rose/javascriptspellcheck.jpg

Comment: please show what you've done so far.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if I understood your question very well, but this code
put some content into a textarea.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <script>

        window.onload = function(){ //when the page is loaded

            document.getElementById('yourtext').value = prompt("Type what dou you wanna appear: ");
            //you take the value of element and put into the content of the prompt
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>

<label for="yourtext">Seu texto</label>
<textarea id="yourtext"></textarea>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this if you want input from user

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#txtTextArea').val(prompt('your msg'));
    });
```

Or try this if you want some predefined static value

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var ranStaticText = ["text1", "text2", "text3", "text4", "text5", "text6"];
    $('#txtTextArea').val(ranStaticText[parseInt(Math.random()*ranStaticText.length)] );
});
```